# How to destructure an id out of an array in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, destructuring

I'm getting an array back from redis (trhough a controller for my projects) which I need to destructure in my product view.

Array (showing 2 results, but it can many more):
`["project-5", "project-4"]`

The numbers (5, 4) are my project id's (@project.id) which I need to subtract to use in a `.each do` function.

All that I can find for it, are destructure solutions for multiple variables. But here I only have 1 variable.

Can anyone help me out with how I can isolate the product id out of this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [match](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/match) method to get the ids with the help of regex. Assuming `array` consists of your projetcs with id-s `3` and `44` then a one-liner would be:

```
2.0.0-p353 :091 > array.map{|el| el.match(/\d+$/)[0]}
  => ["3", "44"]
```

If you sure need to use `.each do` then

```
array.each do |el|
  el.match(/\d+$/)[0]
end
```

You can also use method [gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) with regex to replace everything except the `id` inside string with an empty string, so only id-part of the string will remain. 
One-liner for this (`array = ["proj3ct-3", "project-1567"]`):

```
2.0.0-p353 :040 > array.map {|el| el.gsub(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "")}
  => ["3", "1567"]
```

`.each do` similarly to previous example with `match`.

**EDIT:** If you want the `do`-block to return the array already in formatted form then you should use [bang-method](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub%21) from gsub like this: `el.gsub!(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "")` This will also make changes in elements. Non-bang methods only *return* changed values without altering them.

Just in case you don't know and would like to test/analyze your regex then [this](https://regex101.com/) is a good place to do it- I've been using it for quite a while. Also a good place to recheck some basics is [here](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Andres, that does the job! I'm just experiencing 1 small hick-up: it prints the full array as well after the destructured one. `5 1 ["project-5", "project-1"]`

Comment: I guess you have the problem with `.each do` block not with one-liner?  In that case you can use the bang-method from gsub `el.gsub!(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "")`  . In that case it will return only formatted elements inside array. Bang method will also make changes inside the element not only return the formatted form.

Comment: Then probably something else is going wrong, because even with this method i still have the same outcome: `<div>
     <%= @project_rec.each do |el| %>
     <%= el.gsub!(/(.*\-)[^\d]*/, "") %><br/>
     <% end %>
    </div>`

Comment: But I'll probably be able to figure that out. Thanks so far, @Andres

Comment: Aha- you should remove `=` sign before do-block inside your view. It displays also the return-value from block. :)
But I suggest making a proper method in you corresponding helper file that returns already formatted array. For ex `formatted_project_ids` or sth like that. Then you can print out only id-s by iterating over the method's return value `<%= formatted_project_ids.each do |el|` inside your view. You'll spare your view-files with excessive ruby-logic (for ex describing regex in this example a.s.o.) like that and your app is more structured*

Comment: I know what I did wrong: I made it local. After removing the `@` it only returns each value ones.